# Getting wrong exception handled when enter input into textboxes and press button

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, exception

I keep getting the "Enter an integer" message box when I have both account number and amount to withdraw entered properly.

Say I entered "12" for account number and "50"(or "50.0") for amount - I get the "Enter an integer" exception message box.

If I enter nothing I will get "Enter account number" which is corrent.

If I enter only account number(doesn't matter if the account number exists or not) but leave amount empty - I get nothing from pressing the withdraw button.

If I enter account number and amount(wrong or correctly, doesn't matter) I get the "Enter and integer" exception message box.

Where did I go wrong?

```
private void btnWithdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!txtSearch.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                if(!txtAmount.Text.Equals(""))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int aN = int.Parse(txtSearch.Text);
                        double am = double.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
                        client.Withdraw(aN, am);
                        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Withdrawn {0} from {1}\nBalance now: {2}", am, aN));
                        //if(client.Fi)
                        //    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Customer {0} couldn't be found", aN));
                        //else
                        //    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Customer {0}\nBalance: {1}C", aN, client.CustomerBalance(aN).ToString()));

                    }
                    catch (FormatException)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Enter an integer");
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Customer cannot be found");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter account number");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The format string specifies three arguments, but you have provided only two:

```
String.Format("Withdrawn {0} from {1}\nBalance now: {2}", am, aN)
```

That throws a `FormatException`, but not the one you were thinking about when you wrote the `FormatException` catch block.

To avoid that exception, therefore, you therefore need a way to get the new balance in a variable that you can pass to `String.Format`.  (You would also do well to use longer, more-descriptive variable names than `aN` and `am`.)

The most immediate answer to your question about exception handling would be to use separate try blocks for the separate actions taken by the method, namely, parsing two different strings, performing a transaction, formatting a message to the user, and showing that message.  This would allow separate the handling for the `FormatException` thrown by `int.Parse` from the handling for the `FormatException` thrown by `string.Format`.

However, as Arion suggests, for parsing user input, it's generally better to use `TryParse` rather than catching exceptions (your problem with catching the `FormatException` is a good example of why!).  This, of course, assumes that you are using a version of the framework that *has* the `TryParse` methods; they were added in version 2.0.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved. I'll note the variable naming in the future seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do it like this:

```
int aN;
double am;
if(int.TryParse(txtSearch.Text,out aN) && double.TryParse(txtAmount.Text,out am))
{
    client.Withdraw(aN, am);
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Withdrawn {0} from {1}\nBalance now: {2}", am, aN));
}
else
{
    //Do something
}
```